# Buttons should be as wide as the biggest

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-view

I want all `Button` to fit the text, so there is no line breaks in the `Button`s, but also all the `Button` should has the same width: as wide as the biggest.

I achieved this with setting all the `Button` `layout_width`'s to be `WRAP_CONTENT` in the layout:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Then i search for the biggest value, and set all the buttons to be same sized:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);


    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); ++i) {
        View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
        if (child.getWidth() > size) {
            size = child.getWidth();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); ++i) {
        LayoutParams params = layout.getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams();
        params.width = size;
        layout.getChildAt(i).setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

Is there any cleaner, more elegant solution for this?

Comment: why don't you use LayoutWeight ???

Comment: @VenomVendor these buttons are in a vertical `LinearLayout`, `layout_weight` would effect the height of the `View`s, not the width.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap, all the button inside a common parent Say linearlayout having attributes as wrap_content, wrap_content. use the attributes Match_Parent for your button, now programmatically you just calculate the size of biggest text and set it as parent width, and call layout over it, this will make sure all the child it contains gets resized efficiently.

```
<LinearLayout  <!--Parent-->
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <!-- Child -->
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `TableLayout` and `TableRow` will let the column (in this case, `Button`) has fixed width, depends on the largest/longest one. `android:shrinkColumns` is used in case some of the `Buttons` are longer than screen width to make the word wraps.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:shrinkColumns="0" >
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:text="Short" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:text="Longer text" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:text="Middle" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: I think my answer is a bit overkill (using `Tablelayout` and `TableRow`). Using `LinearLayout` to wrap the children is also possible and perhaps simpler too. But I'll just let my answer here since I think it still works.

Comment: Thanks, Techfist's answer is more suitable here, but this also does the job.

Comment: Perfect for doing all in the layout file.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Use MatchParent instead of WrapContent like below..

```
<Button
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<Button
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: This will set all the buttons to as wide as the parent view (whole screen in this case)...